# Matrix hide columns based on values in column

Tags: sql-server, matrix, reporting-services, hide

I've got a matrix that looks like this:

[image: matrix with my data]

And I would like to hide the column with no data (i.e. second one for the date 21.05...).
I have tried applying expression "IsNothing" and '...Value = ""...' in Visibility field of the Column and of the Group.

How can i get it to hide the "empty" column?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Write This Expression On **Column Visibility Property Of Every Column**.

=IIF(COUNT(Fields![ColumnName].Value) = Cint(0),TRUE,FALSE)